# ROS camera Sensor Gazebo

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have a camera (default gazebo model) in my world.

I launch gazebo using roslaunch.
On trying rostopic list, I do not see any topic published by the camera?

This is the output of rostopic list.

```
/clock
/gazebo/link_states
/gazebo/model_states
/gazebo/parameter_descriptions
/gazebo/parameter_updates
/gazebo/set_link_state
/gazebo/set_model_state
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

How do i use the camera data from my simulation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263745/ros-camera-sensor-gazebo/) by [sritee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30746/sritee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2017-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was making a mistake as I did not add a camera sensor plugin to my world file. Simply copy past the camera plugin lines from the ros plugin tutorials into your .world files, or your robot file, and launch gazebo by roslaunch [packagename] [launchfile].
After adding, rostopic list gives the published image topic. This can be visualized using rviz!

http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_gzplugins

---

Originally posted by [sritee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30746/sritee/) with karma: 28 on 2017-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1